# Where are the many tris located in this model?

Tags: unity, geometry

I have downloaded a Blender model which I like very much.

This model seems to have a really wise geometry, there are not more triangles than necessary. I can judge by switching to Edit mode and having a look at the few triangles.

Now I'm using this Blend file directly in Unity.
Unity shows that the mesh consists of 21K triangles.

I'm really surprised by that because in Blender, there seem to be really few triangles.

However, even Blender displays that there are 21K triangles.

I'm now trying to investigate where exactely the many triangles are.

When I select "slider" in object mode, Blender shows: 21.742 triangles.
When I then try to see where exactely they are, I switch to Edit model.
Now Blender shows "457 triangles":

[image]

How could I find out where these 21K triangles are located?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that there's a subsurface modifier attached to the model.

When I delete it, the tris go down to what I see.